# Access class library through WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a class library for my data objects.  I have a wcf service that references the library and all works well.  I also have a WinForm application that has the wcf service reference.  All works well.  BUT, to use any objects from the class library, I have to have a using statement:

```
using MyClassLibrary;
```

Is there a way to access the objects through the wcf service?  I've added the class library to the wcf project both by project and by dll with the same result.

Thank you.

Comment: If the interface published by the WCF server contains types that are defined in MyClassLibrary, theses types need to be known also in the client, Maybe this is the case here?

Comment: Seems to be too much overhead.  I have to reference it in both projects instead of accessing through wcf.  Something like "using MyService.ClassLibrary".

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly,you want to use the WCF service instead of using a using statement to refer to the library.Or you just don't want to add the using statement.

You can implement it yourself but you have to follow the syntax.

Thanks.

Comment: I want to access through the service, but don't know how.  How do you do that?  In the main app, my client variable only shows the implemented function - no objects or way to get to them.

Comment: You mean add a reference in one project to other project? If I understand correctly, you can try the following steps:
1. In the Solution Explorer window, select the References folder under the project, and then select Add Reference from the shortcut menu.
2. In the Add Reference dialog, under Projects on the left side of the window, select Solution.
3. Select project in the center section of the window, and then select OK.
This action makes the types defined in the project available to the other project.